# custom date filter used with Clarity design isActive not working correctly

Tags: angular, filter, datagrid, vmware-clarity

I created a custom filter that takes in a date range. It works fine; the only problem is the isActive variable; when nothing is selected, which means the value is '', it still shows as active. my code for this custom filter looks like this:

```
  dateRangeFilter: DateRangeFilter;

 constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore, private csvExport: ExportCsvService) {
    
    this.dateRangeFilter = new DateRangeFilter();

  }

export class DateRangeFilter implements ClrDatagridFilterInterface<Transaction | Caregiver> {
  changes = new Subject<any>();
  value: Timestamp | string;
  value2: Timestamp | string;
  property = '';
  operator = '>=';
  operator2 = '<=';

  isActive(): boolean {
    return this.value !== null   && this.value2 !== null;
  }

  accepts(transaction: Transaction | Caregiver) {
    return true;
  }

}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dateRangeFilter.value = '';
    this.dateRangeFilter.value2 = '';
    this.dateRangeFilter.property = 'requestedAt';
    this.dateRangeFilter.operator = '>=';
    this.dateRangeFilter.operator2 = '<=';
  }

pdateDateFilter(event, direction) {
   
    if (direction === 'from') this.dateRangeFilter.value = event.target.value;
    if (direction === 'to') this.dateRangeFilter.value2 = event.target.value;
    const filters = [...STATE.filters];
@@ -264,9 +304,31 @@ export class TransactionsComponent implements OnInit {
        property: this.dateRangeFilter.property,
      });
    console.log(event);
    this.updateState({ ...STATE, filters });
  }

resetDateRangeFilter() {
    this.dateRangeFilter.value = '';
    this.dateRangeFilter.value2 = '';
    this.dateRangeFilter.changes.next(undefined);
  }
```

and the html

```
 <clr-dg-column>
      <ng-container *clrDgHideableColumn="{hidden: false}">
        Date Requested
        <clr-dg-filter [clrDgFilter]="dateRangeFilter">
          <ng-container>
            <label>From</label>
            <input clrInput type="date" name="requestedAt" [value]="dateRangeFilter.value"
                   (change)="updateDateFilter($event, 'from')">
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container>

            <label>To</label>
            <input clrInput type="date" name="requestedAt" [value]="dateRangeFilter.value2"
                   (change)="updateDateFilter($event, 'to')">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-sm" (click)="resetDateRangeFilter()">clear</button>
          </ng-container>
        </clr-dg-filter>
      </ng-container>

    </clr-dg-column>
```

to fix this issue, I know I need to edit this line in the DateRangeFilter:

```
 isActive(): boolean {
    return this.value !== null   && this.value2 !== null;
  }
```

but I have no idea how. If I put return this.value !== '' && this.value2 !== '';
I get an error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should check for `null`, `undefined` and `""`:

```
this.value?.length > 0 && this.value2?.length > 0;
```

You're not mentioning which error are you getting but I assume it's related to the `Timestamp` type since if it's the rxjs one you're using then it's interface is:

```
export interface Timestamp<T> {
  value: T;
  timestamp: number;
}
```

So `isActive` should have some check to account for that as well:

```
isActive(): boolean {
  if (typeof this.value === 'string') {
    return (this.value as string)?.length > 0 && (this.value2 as string)?.length > 0;
  } else {
    return (this.value as Timestamp<string>)?.value?.length > 0 && (this.value as Timestamp<string>)?.value.length > 0;
  }
}
```

Edit:
For firestore based Timestamp the logic in the else should be:

```
return (this.value as Timestamp)?.valueOf()?.length > 0 && (this.value as Timestamp)?.valueOf()?.length > 0;
```

[Live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1wadhp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I should have mentioned the error in my question. The Timestamp is from Firestore (google) not rxjs.  Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Timestamp'.

Comment: Fair enough, the logic should be similar. I've updated my answer based on their documentation.

Comment: it generates the same error I've been getting all along. I will add an image of the errors in dev tools, to the end of my question

Comment: Hmm, from the looks of it I'd say you're passing in an undefind in a firebase function. Could you show the code hat the isActive function enables for execution?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. This is the code for the filter:                                   
    export interface ClrDatagridFilterInterface<T, S = any> {
    isActive(): boolean;
    accepts(item: T): boolean;
    changes: Observable<any>;
    readonly state?: S;
    equals?(other: ClrDatagridFilterInterface<T, any>): boolean;
}

Comment: I assume you have something like:
if (this.isActive()) { // do stuff }
The error seems to be coming from the code in there rather than the check itself.
Without seeing the code itself, my guess is you have within that // do stuff section something like this.afs.someFunc(data) where the data isn't in the expected format